# При (чём): слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Уважаемые филологи! Проконсультируйте, пожалуйста, как написать слово "при(чём)" в предложении: "При (чём) здесь я?" - слитно или раздельно. Внимательно просмотрела справочник по орфографии, но ответ на этот случай не нашла.

Comment: Когда два филолога имеют три мнения - это хороший вопрос.

Comment: Уважаемые филологи, спасибо! Мне самой хотелось написать "При(чем) здесь я?" слитно, но убедили, что надо раздельно. Рада, что есть люди, к которым можно обратиться в сложных случаях. С искренней благодарностью, Элино.

Answer (score 19):

Из орфографического словаря АН под. редакцией Лопатина:

**причём, союз (оби́делся, причём справедли́во), но местоим. при чём (при чём ту́т я́?)**

Comment: Разве здесь (в вопросе) союз? Вы же совсем недавно мне [отвечали][1] на этот же вопрос

>>ПРИЧЁМ I. местоим. нареч. Зачем, с какой стати. П. здесь эти люди? П. тут твоя работа? П. всё это?
У меня именно в таком значении: с какой стати.  



[1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/15309/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Если уж быть точным. Я отвечала в рамках комментария, почему лично я написала в каком-то там предложении это слово слитно. Я чувствую в нем наречие, так и пишу, возможно, ошибочно. Нашла обоснование у Кузнецова. Вот и все. А для ответа на этот вопрос нашла конкретную фразу в словаре (отличную от моего предложения, кстати). Словарь АН для меня доказательство. Давайте на этом остановимся. Вопрос действительно неоднозначный.

Answer (score 6):

Я рассуждаю так. Слово "причём" в 90% случаев пишется слитно, обозначая дополнительную, добавочную информацию. Например, он был интересным собеседником, причём внимательным.  В данном же случае "при чём" является местоимением с предлогом, на него можно ответить "при том". Кроме того, "при чём тут я "  - это синтаксически неделимое словосочетание, обозначающее "я не имею отношения к происходящему".

Answer (score 4):

Есть союз "причем" (Я весел, причем очень), а есть местоимение "чем" с предлогом. В Вашем случае здесь местоимение с предлогом, пишется раздельно

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя в "Справочнике по правописанию и лит. правке" и на: http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.41 такое объяснение:
 Союзы имеют присоединительное значение, синонимичны и легко заменяют друг друга; имеют синонимы да и, вместе с тем, к тому же: Он вернулся через два часа и получил тот же ответ,причем (да и ,притом, к тому же, вместе с тем) лакей как-то косо посмотрел на него (Т.). 
Сочетание при чем употребляется в вопросительных предложениях или в сложноподчиненных предложениях при присоединении изъяснительных придаточных: При чем здесь наши отношения?; Я спросил его, при чем здесь приезжие гости, если они никакого отношения к его работе не имеют. Сочетание при том предполагается в ответе на вопрос, содержащий сочетание при чем:Наши отношения при том, что я не смогу выступить с таким предложением (ответ на вопрос: При чем тут наши отношения?).

У Вас вопросительное предложение, следовательно, раздельно: местоимение ЧТО в предл. пад. с предлогом ПРИ. Присоединительных отношений нет, другим союзом заменить нельзя - это не союз.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52516/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 1):

Слитно. Ответ есть, если внимательно покопаться.
"Причем", "зачем", "почему", "отчего" и т. д. в значении вопросительных местоименных наречий пишутся слитно.

Другое дело, что логичность этого правила под вопросом... Отсюда и разночтения, которые мы можем наблюдать...

У Лопатина, боюсь, неоднозначность.

По большому счету однозначно признать правильность раздельного написания мне не дают только некоторые примеры из классиков...

*― К чему этот насмешливый тон? Причем тут «наследники»? Хотя жена действительно… [Б. Л. Пастернак. Доктор Живаго (1945-1955)]*

Comment: Действительно, когда я прочитала вопрос, сомневалась: то ли наречие здесь, то ли местоимение с предлогом... Понять можно двояко. Возможно, если бы  не заглядывала в словарь, то  и в этом случае написала бы слитно. Но если орфографический словарь АН дает написание конкретного выражения (при чем тут я)раздельно, приходится подчиниться.

Comment: Кстати, спасибо за ответ. Я про его содержательную часть.

Comment: Я в этом словаре вижу не Лопатина прежде всего, а Институт русского языка Академии наук. К таким изданиям меня приучили относится с доверием и уважением. Практически, как к закону.  Других я стараюсь и не приобретать. Кстати, этого у меня нет. Смотрю он-лайн. 

Да, что Лопатин в одном словаре пишет так, а другом эдак - не знала.

Comment: Ларf, Вы можете относиться с уважением или без к авторам, но это не должно мешать видеть плюхи в самом издании. Тем более, что Лопатина не ругал только ленивый.  
Расходится не Лопатин с Лопатиным (это тоже есть, но объяснимо). В первую очередь расходятся Лопатин с Кузнецовым.

Comment: Я не о Лопатине. Я об институте Русского языка. Сказано, пишем раздельно, значит, раздельно. Моя ошибка - пишу по-старому. Для детей буду знать, а в свободном письме вряд ли перестроюсь...

Comment: В самом ИРЯ отношение к Лопатину как минимум неоднозначное. Но это из втнктренняя кухня, я не хочу помогать за них сор из избы выносить.  
Главное, что за словарь непосредственно отвечает тот, под чьей редакцией он создаётся, а не контора, в которой он работает.